# Can I use zxing to generate a code_128 barcode image?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, zxing

I've been fiddling around, but can't seem to find a good documentation for it.

Can I make ZXing generate a CODE_128 barcode image? How?

Comment: **case1**:i generated image from Zen.Barcode.Rendering.Framework. tried to decode with Zxing.net . it didint work.  **case2:** i used advanced configuration that didint work too. but it worked if itself output.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using ZXing.Net you can do it with the following snippet:

```
var content = "123456789012345678";
var writer = new BarcodeWriter
{
   Format = BarcodeFormat.CODE_128
};
var bitmap = writer.Write(content);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on some research this is a possible implementation in MVC:

```
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
       {
           var writer = new BarcodeWriter
           {
                Format = BarcodeFormat.CODE_128
           };
           Bitmap barcodeBitmap;
           var barcode = writer.Write(scan);
           MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
           barcode.Save(memoryStream,ImageFormat.Png);

           ViewBag.OneD = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
     }
```